# target of UITapGestureRecognizer does not get called under iOS 5 anymore

Tags: ios5, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've been using a `UITapGestureRecognizer` for quite some time now to take notice when a tap occurs and to display another view. I'm initializing it like this:

```
_tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showModalDetailView:)];
```

In iOS 4.3, that did work perfectly. In iOS 5, `-showModalDetailView:` does not get called anymore.

I was wondering if anyone else has this issue, too?

**Update**

I'm configuring the recognizer like this:

```
_tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showModalDetailView:)];
_tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
_tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
_tapGesture.delegate = self;
[self addGestureRecognizer:_tapGesture];
```

**Update 2**

Ok, now it gets weird. The code starts working again once I disable the delegate setting by commenting it. However, the delegate methods are still being called. But not always.

The cell has a left aligned title and a right aligned detail text. When you hit the detail text it works as expected: The delegate method does not get called and the popover appears. When you hit the cell somewhere else, the delegate method (`-gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` in this case) gets called and the popover appears.

I don't quite get what's going on here.

Comment: where do you attach that recognizer to?

Comment: In the `- (id)initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` of a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that I implement all three delegate methods (though they're optional) it works. Just returning the default values. Thanks, Dunkelstern and thomas.

Comment: I was facing similar issues. Removing the delegate setting line fixed it, and that's when I realized it was a silly mistake on my part to set the recognizer's delegate, because it does not have a custom protocol with callbacks. Adding a target and selector should be more than enough. Which brings me to ask you, what are the three delegate methods you're speaking of in your answer?

Comment: Sid, the methods I implemented were the ones defined in `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`. I needed the `-gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` to determine whether the view should receive the tap. I was using another view on top of it which should not fire the event when tapped.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks! I was looking for UITapGestureRecognizerDelegate :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting numberOfTouchesRequired and numberOfTapsRequired to 1 explicitly.
And of course you have to call addGestureRecognizer on your View instance.